# Flutter & Cloud-Firestore: how to read Firestore Documents linked to Flutter FutureBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Scenario explained:
Using: import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

Cloud Firestore:
a Collection 'sessionsLog', containing documents with the following fields:
'sessionId' a String
'isClosed' a bool
'locationId' a String and some other fields ...

I want to retrieve all documents with a false bool for 'isClosed', only once, and then perform some actions. Therefore I chose to use a FutureBuilder (not a streambuilder), what I did:

```
    FutureBuilder(
    future: Firestore.instance.collection('sessionsLog')
    .where('isClosed', isEqualTo: false).getDocuments();
    builder: (ctx, sessionSnapshot) {
    return  RaisedButton(
    child: Text('Search'),
    onPressed: () async {
    //some other code here, that needs async I added on top

    if (sessionSnapshot.connectionState !=
                        ConnectionState.done) {
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
    if (!sessionSnapshot.hasData) {i should 
                      print('nothing to show here');
                    }else {
    //the below line of code is wrong, it could be print / or Text / or any other widget
    //I've just added it for the sake of an example.
    print(sessionSnapshot.data.documents[0]['parkingLocationName']);}});}),
```

The above code is not working, I've just created it for a simple code result, to just be able to print values I am retrieving, so please don't fix something in my code.

Also noting that, in my code logic, there will always be once single document with `'isClosed' = false`. So, I should always receive one single document.

But If it differs, please give me 2 examples, one if retrieved data contains 1 single document and another if there could be several documents and therefore how would I iterate in the data.

I just want the correct way to be able to READ/access the data I am receiving, whether to print the fields info, or display them in a text. anything, but how would I do that, in the exact explained above scenarios.

Would really appreciate a simple sample example based on my code scenario.

Comment: I am not sure about the first problem you are facing here but if there could be multiple documents returned by your query and you only care about one, you should probably look at ```limit``` and ```orderBy``` in the Firestore documentation.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks mate. But this is not about how to filter. My aim is as to how to read the fields data, how to access them. Whether receiving a single or many documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in a future like this:

```dart
Future<void> performActionsOnClosed() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('sessionsLog')
        .where('isClosed', isEqualTo: false)
        .get()
        .then(
      (snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
          // Perform actions
        } else {
          print('No Documents Found');
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, simply put! Now that I look at it, it wasn't complicated, but checking many scenarios and code online just made me go blank.
If you don't mind, aside from courses that build an app while explaining what they are using. Any online documentations you know of, that can really assist?
Example, for Cloud_firestore plugin with Flutter, I'm struggling to find clear documentations? Firebase documentations gives you a generalized code to be used with everything except for flutter. and the plugin itself cloud_firestore.dart has almost 0 explanation.
Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: check out this video from fireship.io: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFxk_KJCqgk&list=PL0vfts4VzfNiQYtnn1TZ6U0Ec_vjCN9VY&index=8 He's got some great Flutter videos.  IMO the best way to learn is to try to break things then try to understand what's going wrong.